# Convert php variables to json

Tags: php, json

I have the two more php variable array how i convert this into json

```
  $tmp[0]
  $tmp[1]
  $tmp[2]
  $tmp[3]
```

i have tried

```
$json_array=array(
  "dir"=>$tmp[0],
  "sym"=>$tmp[1],
   "bid"=>$tmp[2],
    "ask"=>$tmp[3]
);

echo json_encode($json_array);
```

it shows

```
{"dir":"down","sym":"oo","b":"1.35460","a":"1.35465"} {"dir":"down","sym":"pp","b":"1.64263","a":"1.64273"} {"dir":"down","sym":"qq","b":"104.498","a":"104.502"} {"dir":"up","sym":"rr","b":"0.88183","a":"0.88188"} {"dir":"down","sym":"ss","b":"1.09551","a":"1.09558"}
```

but i need to change like this

```
[{"dir":"down","sym":"oo","b":"1.35460","a":"1.35465"},{"dir":"down","sym":"pp","b":"1.64263","a":"1.64273"},{"dir":"down","sym":"qq","b":"104.498","a":"104.502"},{"dir":"up","sym":"rr","b":"0.88183","a":"0.88188"},{"dir":"down","sym":"ss","b":"1.09551","a":"1.09558"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create the data structure you want with php arrays and then `json_encode($data);`

If you want an additional array wrapper: (I'm using the more modern array syntax)

```
$data = [[ //or array(array(
  "dir"=>$tmp[0],
  "sym"=>$tmp[1],
  "bid"=>$tmp[2],
  "ask"=>$tmp[3]
]]; // or ))

$data = json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Also don't forget to first set your content type header: header('Content-type: application/json');

Answer (score 2):

Just do json Encode using Php function json_encode()

```
$json=json_encode($json_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to json_enoce of your array:

```
$json_array=array(
  "dir"=>$tmp[0],
  "sym"=>$tmp[1],
   "bid"=>$tmp[2],
    "ask"=>$tmp[3]
);
print_r(json_encode($json_array));
```

It will print the JSON representation of `$json_array`

documentation: https://www.php.net/json_encode

Answer (score 0):

Use **[Json Encode](https://www.php.net/json_encode)** to convert it to a PHP.

```
$data = array(
    "dir"=>$tmp[0],
    "sym"=>$tmp[1],
    "bid"=>$tmp[2],
    "ask"=>$tmp[3]
);

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Definitely not what the OP is asking

Answer (score 0):

```
$json_array=array();
json_object1=array(
  "dir"=>$tmp[0],
  "sym"=>$tmp[1],
   "bid"=>$tmp[2],
    "ask"=>$tmp[3]
);
$json_array[]=json_object1;
$json_object2=array(
  "dir"=>$tmp[0],
  "sym"=>$tmp[1],
   "bid"=>$tmp[2],
    "ask"=>$tmp[3]
);
$json_array[]=json_object2;
json_encode($json_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this .

```
$json_array=array(
  "dir"=>$tmp[0],
  "sym"=>$tmp[1],
   "bid"=>$tmp[2],
    "ask"=>$tmp[3]
);

echo json_encode(array($json_array));
```

Output :

```
[{"dir":null,"sym":null,"bid":null,"ask":null}]
```